# Rails 4. Loading indicator between pages without Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, loading

I am trying to make a loading indicator between different pages without Ajax. I have a div with .spin-wrapper class containing gif. So I need it to be hidden when page is loaded, and to be shown when I click a link. When new page is loaded it should become hidden again (and so on).

But it works just once when I reload a page. It loads and hides my div, then show it after I click on a link (console messages appear). But then it doesn't work. I see my div on any other page and my console messages don't appear as well.

Application.js:

```
function toggleSpin() {
    $('.spin-wrapper').toggle()
    console.log('clicked');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip_cell').tooltip({container: 'body'})

    $('.spin-wrapper').hide()
    $('a').on('click',toggleSpin);
    console.log('loaded');

});
```

How to fix it?

Comment: but... you aren't using ajax. as soon as you click that link, the current page is unloaded and the new page begins to load. you can't really do a loading bar on the previous page because it will be destroyed when the previous page is unloaded (which will be near instantly), it'l all have to be handled on the target page.

Comment: @KevinB, do you have any ideas how to handle it?

Comment: No, because you can't. If you want loading bars, it would be better to use ajax. Without ajax, there isn't much need for loading bars because by the time you can display one, the page will likely be done loading. (unless of course it's a graphic heavy page, but that's a different situation entirely.)

Comment: @KevinB can I show indicator before new page is loaded somehow? Now it takes 4-5 seconds when cache is updated, so I would like to let user know that everything is all right.

Comment: 4-5 seconds on which side of the request? before the new page begins to load, or before the new page is done loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using rails 4 and Turbolink maybe your problem is that your javascript code is only loaded once. Try disabling Turbolink (in asset/application.js) and test your code. If it works and you want to keep using Turbolink, I recommend this https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks
Check this too!
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/
http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks

Answer (score 2):

> I have a div with .spin-wrapper class containing gif. So I need it to be hidden when page is loaded, and to be shown when I click a link. When new page is loaded it should become hidden again (and so on).

The div will no longer exist shortly after clicking your link, therefore it will be again hidden when you reach the new page since it is defaulted to hidden. Instead, default it to visible, then on window load, hide it.

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    $(".spin-wrapper").fadeOut();
});
```

You can of course still show it after clicking the link too if you wish.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    $(".spin-wrapper").fadeIn();
});
```

Showing it on click however may result in it not being very smooth because the spinner will go away, and then show again.

Comment: The same. It works only the first time or when I reload the page. Then I see this div on every page on my site. Load event is being triggered only once..

Comment: It should only be triggering once, and that should be more than enough if you're not using ajax as suggested in your question. I think you actually are using ajax and just don't know it.

Comment: how could I check it for sure? I don't use by myself, but maybe Rails or Bootstrap do..

Comment: Look in the network tab of your console, filter it to xhr, then reload the page and click a few links.

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses turbolinks so we should use

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:click', function() {
  $('#your_spinner_div').removeClass('hide-div');
});
```

where,

```
.hide-div{
  display: none;
}
```

also add

```
    $( document ).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function() {
  $('#your_spinner_div').addClass('hide-div');
});
```

so you wont see the spinner when clicking browser back.

Posting this answer because i have tried adding the snippets in above answers and didn't work. Hope this will help in the future who are new to rails.